# Can I have 2 free adjacent nodes in the fit algorithm for data management

Tags: algorithms, memory-management, memory-allocation

so I know we can have 2 busy adjacent nodes for the fit algo since there'll always be free memory available, but what about when it comes to 2 free adjacent nodes? Is it possible to have 2 adjacent free nodes and why? Thanks

Comment: `the fit algo` is that a reference to the Inconvenient AlGore?

Comment: it's the first-fit, best-fit or worst-fit for data management